# Conditioning on probability zero as a limit

Tags: probability-theory

I'm studying stochastic processes and am trying to relate different notions of conditional expectation/probability. There is an interesting way in which we can condition on an event of probability zero when we have two jointly continuously distributed random variables $X,Y$:

$$\mathbb{P}(X \in B\mid Y=y):=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}{\mathbb{P}\left( X \in B\mid y-\epsilon<Y<y+\epsilon\right)}$$

Now the Wikipedia article on this claims that such a limit always exists if the marginal density function of $Y$ is positive, and gives the following proof:

> For example, if two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ have a joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, then by L'Hôpital's rule:
>
> $$\begin{align*}
> \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}P(Y \in U \mid x_0 - \epsilon \lt X \lt x_0 + \epsilon)&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{\int^{x_0+\epsilon}_{x_0-\epsilon}\int_U f_{X,Y}(x,y)\text{d}y\text{d}x}{\int^{x_0+\epsilon}_{x_0-\epsilon} \int_\mathbb{R} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\text{d}y\text{d}x}\\[5pt]
> &=\frac{\int_U f_{X,Y}(x_0,y)\text{d}y}{\int_\mathbb{R}f_{X,Y}(x_0,y)\text{d}y}.\\[5pt]
> \end{align*}$$
>
> The resulting limit is the conditional property distribution of $Y$ given $X$ and exists when the denominator, the probability density $f_X(x_0)$, is strictly positive.

Could someone explain to me how this is an application of L'Hôpital's rule? I would also like to know why, given this seemingly perfectly adequate definition, we need to bother with conditioning on $\sigma$-algebras at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This definition is not adequate if 1) - the variables in question do not have densities, or 2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox

Answer (score 2):

**Explain how this is an application of L'Hôpital's rule**

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X \in B|y-\epsilon<Y<y+\epsilon) 
&= \frac {\mathbb{P}(X \in B,y-\epsilon<Y<y+\epsilon)}{\mathbb{P}(y-\epsilon<Y<y+\epsilon)}\\
&=\frac{\int^{x_0+\epsilon}_{x_0-\epsilon} \int_U f_{X,Y}(x,y)\text{d}x\text{d}y}{\int^{x_0+\epsilon}_{x_0-\epsilon} \int_\mathbb{R} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\text{d}x\text{d}y}
\end{align}
$$
Denote $F(\epsilon) = \int^{x_0+\epsilon}_{x_0-\epsilon} \int_U f_{X,Y}(x,y)\text{d}x\text{d}y$ and
$G(\epsilon)=\int^{x_0+\epsilon}_{x_0-\epsilon} \int_\mathbb{R} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\text{d}x\text{d}y$ , we note that $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} F(\epsilon) = 0$
and $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} G(\epsilon) = 0$, then we want to know
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac {F(\epsilon)}{G(\epsilon)}
$$
This is the form $\frac 00$.

To use L'Hôpital's rule , we need know
$F'(0)$ and $G'(0)$ which as above